# Eloquent doesn't return what it expects

Tags: php, laravel-4

I actually have a problem that drives me crazy. 
I'm a noob in laravel, i did a tuto last week and try to learn with real project.

I have a 1 to many relationship between my Users and Projects (one user can create many project)

That are my 2 models :

```
class Project extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'projects';
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'description');
    public  $timestamps = true; 

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

And my User model :

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';
    public  $timestamps = true;  
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Task');
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Project', 'created_by');
    }

}
```

Then when I tried to get my projects to display them with the data of the user linked to it and it gave me something strange. 
Here is my method :

```
    public function lists()
    {
        $projects = Project::all();//with('user')->get();
        return compact('projects');
    }
```

When i do that instead of the request with the 'with' to make a join it give that (with var_dump)

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[316]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(Project)[314]
          protected 'table' => string 'projects' (length=8)
          public 'timestamps' => boolean true
          protected 'connection' => null
          protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
          protected 'perPage' => int 15
          public 'incrementing' => boolean true
          protected 'attributes' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
          protected 'original' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
          protected 'relations' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'hidden' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'visible' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'appends' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'fillable' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'guarded' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'dates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'touches' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'observables' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'with' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'morphClass' => null
          public 'exists' => boolean true
```

I have my exemple from the tuto i did but i did excatly the same and it doesn't work.
I expect to get something like that:

```
object(Post)[407]
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'titre' (length=5)
      1 => string 'contenu' (length=7)
      2 => string 'user_id' (length=7)
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'table' => null
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 100
      'created_at' => string '2014-12-02 16:22:54' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-12-02 16:22:54' (length=19)
      'titre' => string 'Titre99' (length=7)
      'contenu' => string 'Contenu 99 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud                     exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur                sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.' (length=492)
      'user_id' => int 8
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 100
      'created_at' => string '2014-12-02 16:22:54' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-12-02 16:22:54' (length=19)
      'titre' => string 'Titre99' (length=7)
      'contenu' => string 'Contenu 99 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud                     exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur                sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.' (length=492)
      'user_id' => int 8
  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=2)
      'user' => 
        object(User)[420]
          protected 'table' => string 'users' (length=5)
          public 'timestamps' => boolean true
          protected 'hidden' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected 'connection' => null
          protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
          protected 'perPage' => int 15
          public 'incrementing' => boolean true
          protected 'attributes' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
          protected 'original' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
          protected 'relations' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'visible' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'appends' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'fillable' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'guarded' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'dates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'touches' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'observables' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'with' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'morphClass' => null
          public 'exists' => boolean true
      'tags' => 
        object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[450]
          protected 'items' => 
            array (size=4)
              ...
  protected 'hidden' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'visible' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'appends' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '*' (length=1)
  protected 'dates' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'touches' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'observables' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'with' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'morphClass' => null
  public 'exists' => boolean true
```

If someone know why, I'll bless you !!

Comment: Rather than var_dump the collection object, do `var_dump($collection->toArray())` to dump the data from the collection..... but you're also `compact` ing the result of yoru projects query, why?

Comment: I learn it that way in the tuto i did and when i var_dump the same kind of data, one return me collection object and the right one (which works) return me an occurence of the right object

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving all records, thats why you have a [0], its an array (collection) of projects

Try dump only one project

```
$projects = Project::all();
var_dump($projects->first());
```

Comment: I want to get all project, for the moment i only have one in my DB

Comment: I know what you mean but the var_dump is already in a foreach but when i do ->first(), it gives me the Project occurence, but in my other project when i did the same i didn't need to use ->first() or something like that to get my object.